# Need to save an apex:inlineEditSupport to apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, controller, pageblocktable

I am stuck at one point...First I had to make an apex:column editable, which is done. Now the second point is that when the user enters a value in editable apex:column, I need to store that value in respective Object.

Apex Column

```
<apex:column style="width: 200px">
    <apex:outputField value="{!Varsion.con.Additional_Email__c}" id="additionalEmail">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton"/>
    </apex:outputField>
    <apex:facet name="header">CC Email</apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

Save Button

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{!saveButton}" id="saveButton" />
```

Controller Code

```
public void saveButton(){
    List<ContentVersion> selectedIds = new List<ContentVersion>();
    List<ContentVersion> cver = new List<ContentVersion>();
    // Getting ids of selected records to be updated
    for(VersionWrapper vh: getIds()) {
        if(vh.selected == true) {
            selectedIds.add(vh.con);
        }
    }        
    List<ContentVersion> contVerList = [Select Additional_Email__c from ContentVersion where Id IN: selectedIds];
    for(ContentVersion c:contVerList)
    {

        c.Additional_Email__c = 'Test'; // Here I want to get the values of edited email address...   
        cver.add(c);
    }        
    update cver;       
    refreshGrid();                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changed values will be automatically set in the `Additional_Email__c`  fields of the collection that you used to output the table. So loop over that collection and base the update on those values. You haven't posted enough code for anything but a conceptual answer so:

```
List<ContentVersion> updates = new List<ContentVersion>();
for (CollectionType item : collection) {
    if (item...selected) {
        Id id = item...Id;
        String email = item...Additional_Email__c;
        updates.add(new ContentVersion(Id = id, Additional_Email__c = email));
    }
}
update updates;
```

Comment: Keith! It worked...
if (item...selected) {
        Id id = item...Id;
        String email = item...Additional_Email__c;
        updates.add(new ContentVersion(Id = id, Additional_Email__c = email));
    }

It worked like a charm! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the code you've provided, I think there's at least a couple of pieces that you've missed or where your code suggests there may be some confusion. I've commented and adjusted your code with what I think might be helpful.

```
public void saveButton(){
    List<ContentVersion> selectedIds = new List<ContentVersion>();
    // If a list of ContentVersion Object Records & NOT IDs, this is poor naming
    // If these are Ids, then you've declared your list improperly which affects your code below

    // List<ContentVersion> cver = new List<ContentVersion>();
    // not needed

    for(VersionWrapper vh: getIds()) {
        if(vh.selected == true) {
            selectedIds.add(vh.con);
        }
    }        
    // It would have been helpful to your question if you'd included the related code 
    // You show a method called getIds that you add to list<VersionWrapper>
    // So again, are they Ids or are they VersionWrapper Object Records?

    List<ContentVersion> contVerList = [Select Additional_Email__c from ContentVersion where Id IN: selectedIds];
    // Confusion continues here where ID IN: selectedIds since not a list of Ids

    for(ContentVersion c:contVerList)
    {    
        c.Additional_Email__c = 'Test'; // Here I want to get the values of edited email address...   
        // cver.add(c);
        // it isn't necessary to add these to a new list
    }

    update contVerList;
    // I've assumed the query is only related to what's displayed and will be
    // regenerated if another selection is made so can be directly updated

    refreshGrid();
    // I assume this requeries your records & refreshes the page       
}
```